# Trouble creating line graph on numbers with multiple variables

Tags: numbers, graphics

I have little to no knowledge when it comes to Numbers/other data programmes. I’m working with a client and I want to create a line graph to show how these variables affect each other (eg. Does food consumption/exercise affect sleep) but i’m having no luck. Is it even possible or would I need to only select two variables (including/excluding the date?) As you can see, despite selecting the table I want to use, the line graph produced seems to be completely unrelated?

I’ve also tried creating a line graph with just two variables (see below) but the graph still doesn’t seem to make sense. I don’t want anything fancy, just an easy way to view how different variables affect each other

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bit of a statistics problem as much as a Numbers problem.

On the statistics side, you are trying to compare, for example, daily sleep time with daily food intake. However, you are measuring food intake a bit like a [categorical rather than a quantitative variable](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/1/1.1/1.1.1). Then, Numbers can not compare the food intakes because it can not say, for example, if "Low" is less than or greater than "Medium". So, you have to use a numeric scale such as 0 to 5 for daily food intake with 0 indicating "no food" and 5 "significantly above average".

On the Numbers side, you need to use a [scatter chart](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/1/1.1/1.1.1) rather than a line chart. Below is the screenshot of an example based on your data:

[image]

Given where the dots are congregated, I would say the chart shows that your client's daily food intake appears to increase when the sleep taken is decreased, especially when it is less than 6 hours.